# How is GDB "info variables" output composed?

Tags: c, gdb

I wanted to obtain the list of all global and static variables in my program and so I thought of using GDB "info variables" to obtain it. It was obviously a very large output (which I redirected to a file by setting logging and turning off pagination). What struck me was many variables were recurring in this output. I wish to understand why.

For example : `static const char * const rc_error_name[64];`

I understand that static variables are copied for every translation unit. Is that why we would see static variables recurring in the global output?

If so, why is it that when I executed info var <var_name> for this variable, I see only one entry :

```
(gdb) info var rc_error_name
All variables matching regular expression "rc_error_name":

File /mypath/to/include/some_header.h:
static const char * const rc_error_name[64];
```

Another variable type I noticed recurring in the output was enums.

Apologies if this is a silly question, I hope to verify if my understanding is correct so I do not presume.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that static variables are copied for every translation unit. Is that why we would see static variables recurring in the global output?

Correct.

> why is it that when I executed info var <var_name> for this variable, I see only one entry

Likely because of [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13590#c2).